# Regex to find instance of a number in a string

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string that is like the following

```
32686_8 is number 2
```

I am new to using regex and want some help. I want two different patterns, firstly to find

> 32686_8

and then another one to find

> 2

hope you can help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following to match:

```
([\\d_]+)\\D+(\\d+)
```

And extract out `$1` and `$2`

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iM0mH8/1)

Code:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^([\\d_]+)\\D+(\\d+)$").matcher(str);
while(m.find())
{
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
  System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use capturing groups.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^(\\S+).*?(\\S+)$").matcher(str);
if(m.find())
{
System.out.println(m.group(1));
System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```

OR

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^\\S+|\\S+$").matcher(str);
while(m.find())
{
System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

`^\\S+` matches one or more non-space chars present at the start. Likewise, `\\S+$` matches one or more non-space characters present at the end.

OR

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\b\\d+(?:_\\d+)*\\b").matcher(str);
while(m.find())
{
System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zC8mG5/6)